# Unable to start app on boot, copied on system folder (should not be related to Android 3.0 security fix)

Tags: android

I am trying to get my app to load on bootup. Once loaded, I also need to dynamically (thats why the intent-filter is set to false) listen for network connected status.

Manifest file

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.mycompany.support.AutoStartOnBoot"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver
    android:name="com.mycompany.support.AutoStartOnWifi"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Code for OnBoot

```
public class AutoStartOnBoot extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static Intent intent;
public static Context context;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Here after some processing
    PackageManager pm = AutoStartOnBoot.context.getPackageManager();
    ComponentName compName = new ComponentName(AutoStartOnBoot.context,
                                               AutoStartOnWifi.class);
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(compName,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    // This should enable the other receiver
```

Code for Network Connectivity

```
public class AutoStartOnWifi extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
```

I have a feeling that if I delete the AutoStartOnWifi receiver from the manifest it will start working.

**Permissions**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I have placed the apk in the system folder (so the Android 3.1 inactive app thingy too does not impact me).

Comment: Why don't you register the receiver using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver, android.content.IntentFilter) Rather then using manifest. So you will not have to enable disable it.. You can also unregister when you want.

Comment: Trying out registering programmatically. But I wonder does it have anything to do with `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />`

Comment: But why you need `android.intent.category.DEFAULT` ? Since there aren't any other receivers in your manifest which have these two intent filters.